# jQuery each in a each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I will create a dynamic webshop product loader and have this i array output from my system.

```
{"product":[{"picture":".jpg","title":"test","category":"varenummer","price":"500,00 kr.","onStock":"1","status":"test"},{"picture":".jpeg","title":"test test","category":"varenummerssss","price":"550,00 kr.","onStock":"5","status":"test s"}]}
```

i don't know how i can create this each loop out.

Comment: this is JSON format, are you familiar with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is overkill to loop through a list.

Fairly straight forward and very simplified:

```
var list = {"product":[{"picture":".jpg","title":"test","category":"varenummer","price":"500,00 kr.","onStock":"1","status":"test"},{"picture":".jpeg","title":"test test","category":"varenummerssss","price":"550,00 kr.","onStock":"5","status":"test s"}]};
var i, len, product;
for(i = 0, len = list.product.length; i < len; i++)
{
    product = list.product[i];
    alert(product.picture + " and " + product.title);
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/QBD2b/)

Comment: agree with you, but what about the second loop? and all your variables?

Comment: @AndreasAL, there is actually no need for a second loop. The properties of the object are available as shown in my edit.

Comment: i know... but most of the time - at least for me - i want to dynamically do the same stuff with all "name:string"'s from an object. Maybe execute one but more or less print the rest out - **in a 2th loop**

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = {"product":[{"picture":".jpg","title":"test","category":"varenummer","price":"500,00 kr.","onStock":"1","status":"test"},{"picture":".jpeg","title":"test test","category":"varenummerssss","price":"550,00 kr.","onStock":"5","status":"test s"}]}
$.each(data.product, function() {
    $.each(this, function(key, value) {
        // key = picture, title, etc
        // value = .jpg, test, etc
    });
});
```

in `jQuery.each` the second argument is set as `this` for the scope. So `this === arguments[1]`